# Java Checkbox in applet program

Tags: java, checkbox, parameters, applet

```
Dental = new Checkbox("Dental");
Vision = new Checkbox("Vision");
```

I'm creating new checkboxes named dental and vision. I've implemented `ItemListener` and everything done perfect.  But the above two statements throw an error like

"`checkbox` cannot be applied to given types". required :No arguments. found: `java.lang.String.` actual and formal arguments differ in length.

Please help me.

Comment: You realise you're using AWT? How are `Dental` and `Vision` declared?

Comment: Checkbox Dental, Vision; //Declaration

Comment: Did you override Checkbox?  A one string contructor is valid for java.awt.Checkbox.  If you have created your own class called Checkbox or you are pointing to the wrong Checkbox (some other library) that could cause your problems.